# how to get Property value in one line of code from Task<T>

Tags: c#

I have a class model like this:

```
public class WhiteLabelModel
{
    public string  ContactNumber { get; set; }
}
```

A service class like this:

```
public class WhiteLabel : IWhiteLabel
{
    public async Task<WhiteLabelModel> GetWhiteLabel(string HostName)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        WhiteLabelModel wl = new WhiteLabelModel { ContactNumber = "abc" };

        return wl;
    }
}
```

and I am calling GeWhiteLabel in order to get ContactNumber value with two lines of code

```
var obj = await _whiteLabel.GetWhiteLabel("aaa").ConfigureAwait(false);
var value = obj.ContactNumber;
```

I wonder if I can use just one line of code instead of two in order to get the ContactNumber value using await and ConfigureAwait(false)?

Comment: Sure, just replace `obj` in the second line with the first expression (in parentheses) - though I'm not sure what exactly that gains you

Comment: Or just return the value that you want if there are no other callers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = (await _whiteLabel.GetWhiteLabel("aaa").ConfigureAwait(false)).ContactNumber;
```

Whether that improves or reduces readability is ... subjective.